# Geometry -Length of triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the diagram $AB=6\,\mathrm{cm}, \,AC=10\,\mathrm{cm}, \,DE=4\,\mathrm{cm}$. What is the length of $AD$ (in $\mathrm{cm}$)?

[image]

---

I am searching for concept used to find out length of triangle as per the diagram in attachment. I do have an answer from worksheet as 14/3 but cannot find reason behind it. Shall appreciate if someone can advise on this. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Conceps are basic ones, which I'm sure you already know.

Comment: The triangles are similar, so their sides are proportional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find $\overline{BC} = \sqrt{10^2-6^2} = 8$, and since $\Delta DEC$ is similar to $\Delta ABC$, we have $\overline{DC} = \frac{16}{3}$ (and $\overline{EC} = \frac{20}{3}$). So $\overline{AD} = 10 - \frac{16}{3} = \frac{14}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks. Did you use Pythagoras theorem again to get side  EC and Side DC. Just wondering how 20/3 for EC was calculated

Comment: @VivRichardsfan No, I used the fact that the two triangles are similar. Side $\overline{ED}$ is similar to side $\overline{AB}$. Similarly, $\overline{EC}$ is similar to $\overline{AC}$ and $\overline{DC}$ is similar to $\overline{BC}$. Since $\overline{ED} = \frac{2}{3} \overline{AB}$, we know that $\overline{EC} = \frac{2}{3} \overline{AC}$ and $\overline{DC} = \frac{2}{3}\overline{BC}$.

Comment: @VivRichardsfan If you have any more questions or need additional clarification, feel free to ask! Otherwise, please choose a best answer (now and in future questions) so that your question gets removed from the "Unanswered" tab.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation.  I can now explain this to my kid who could not find notes about reason behind it nor googling gave much information as it was a worksheet without explanation and I too had difficulty in remembering school stuff which I have forgotten. I have already voted for your answer as correct. Is there any thing I need to do from my side as answered